# problem with my other windows installation on another drive

Tags: boot, grub2, windows

I used bootrepair on my new Ubuntu installation but that broke my windows installation on another drive. Now I cannot boot into windows anymore without my Ubuntu drive, and that is a problem because they are not supposed to be in the same computer.

When i try to boot my windows drive without the Ubuntu drive I get stuck at a GNU GRUB command promt. I am very new to managing boot controllers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know other solutions than by reinstalling Windows. It is better to first try to manually repair Ubuntu instead of using a bootrepair because you never know what the bootrepair is going to do.

Answer (score 0):

So I understand correctly: You have/had a dual boot of windows and ubuntu, and now the boot loader is broken and you can't get into windows?

If you have removed ubuntu and all you get is grub, it's because your boot loader was replaced by grub. You need to download a Windows repair ISO for a USB stick, or a Windows installation media from Microsoft. Boot your computer from USB and then run the boot repair commands. This will fix your boot loader and allow you to launch Windows again. No need to install Windows again the boot loader is the only thing corrupted.